# When UIImagePickerController delegate didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo will be called?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When the source is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, will the delegate be called as soon as the photo is shot or will it be called when the “Use Photo” button is clicked in preview screen? I couldn't debug it as I don't have a iDevice and as it will not work in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method will get called when you choose the option `Use photo`. Till that point you can take as many pictures as you want and the delegate method will not get called till you select any photo and pressed the `use photo` option

The same thing with photo library, the delegate method will get called when you selected the Choose otpion.

**From the Documentation:**

> Tells the delegate that the user picked a still image or movie.

Comment: So it will be called only the photo is selected or when you click on Use Photo to tell the user picked a still image or movie.